# Can I fail a build based on the outcome of a SSH Task?

Tags: ssh, bamboo

I was wondering if I could use bamboo's SSH task to run a script (this kicks off a small java message injector).

Then grep the logs for ERRORS. If any ERROR is present I would like to fail the build.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this a Bash question or is it really about Bamboo? Here is the Bash problem answer:

If you run

```
[[ ! $(grep ERROR /a/directory/log/*) ]]
```

the script will exit with an error if it finds the word "ERROR" anywhere in the files.

Bamboo should detect the task execution as failed.

(Note that if Bash is not the default shell on your target system you may need a `#!/bin/bash` on top of the script file.)

Comment: So yes this works. Non zero exit code's cause the bamboo build to fail. My question was more to do with bamboo however. I was hoping bamboo would be able to capture more than just exit codes. As a workaround I am having to write a script that does the log checking and if it contains specific errors I exit with a non zero exit code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Mick if this answer solves the problem, do you mind to accept it as the solution? Thanks.